# Nested table in Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I'm bit confused on how would i patch in multiple columns and rows on my ingredients. Since one ingredient have several expiry date. They have to be separated. But each ingredient has its own available quantity. But they also have one whole Approved Quantity. I need to check also the `Approved Quantity` and the `Available Quantity` when i type on the `Quantity To Transfer`. Here's a more clearer picture of what i'm saying below.

[image]

> ts

```
    .......
    .subscribe(
        (data:any) => {
            this.request = data.requestStock[0];
            console.log(data); 
            this.patchValues();

        },
        error => {
            console.log(error); 
        })
}

patchValues() {
    let rows = this.patchForm.get('rows') as FormArray;
    this.request.delivery_items[0].ingredient.warehouse_items.forEach(data => {
        rows.push(this.fb.group({
            ingredient_id: data.ingredient.id,
            ingredient_sku: data.ingredient.SKU,
            ingredient_name: data.ingredient.name,
            approved_quantity: this.request.delivery_items[0].approved_quantity,
            expiration_date: data.expiration_date,
            available_quantity: data.available_stocks,
            transferred_quantity: [null, Validators.required],
            unit: this.request.delivery_items[0].unit.name
        }))
    })
}
```

> HTML

```
  <tr *ngFor="let row of patchForm.controls.rows.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i">
  <td>{{row.value.ingredient_sku}}</td>
  <td>{{row.value.ingredient_name}}</td>
  <td>{{row.value.approved_quantity }}</td>
  <td>{{row.value.expiration_date }}</td>
  <td>{{row.value.available_quantity }}</td>
  <td>{{ row.value.transferred_quantity }}
    <div class="error" *ngIf="row.hasError('out')">Your Quantity Exceeded The Available Approved Quantity</div>
    <div class="error" *ngIf="row.hasError('out2')">Your Quantity Exceeded The Available Warehouse Quantity</div>
  </td>
  <td>{{row.value.unit}}</td>
  <td>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-square btn-danger btn-sm waves-effect waves-light" (click)="onDeleteRow(i)"> <i class="icofont icofont-ui-delete"></i> Remove</button>
 </td>
</tr>
```

> JSON

```
{
      "token": "eyJ0eXAiO",
      "requestStock": [
        {
          "id": 6,
          "requested_by": 1,
          "approved_by": 1,
          "requested_date": "2018-01-28",
          "approved_date": "2018-01-28",
          "outlet_id": 5,
          "request_stock_number": "RS-201800000006",
          "status": "Approved",
          "delivery_status": "Open",
          "created_at": "2018-01-28 14:17:23",
          "updated_at": "2018-01-28 14:17:31",
          "delivery_items": [
            {
              "id": 21,
              "ingredient_id": 1,
              "request_stock_id": 6,
              "request_quantity": 100,
              "approved_quantity": 100,
              "delivered_quantity": 0,
              "delivery_status": "Open",
              "unit": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Gram",
                "abbreviation": "g",
                "lowest_unit": "Yes",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
              },
              "created_at": null,
              "updated_at": "2018-01-28 14:17:31",
              "ingredient": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Cafe Latte Powder",
                "description": "Cafe Latte Powder",
                "SKU": "1000000",
                "purchase_price": 400,
                "vat": 10,
                "asset_account": 3,
                "cogs_account": 14,
                "expense_account": 11,
                "sales_account": 13,
                "default_unit": 2,
                "purchase_unit": 1,
                "created_at": "2018-01-18 08:30:37",
                "updated_at": "2018-01-18 08:30:37",
                "warehouse_items": [
                  {
                    "id": 1,
                    "ingredient_id": 1,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "receive_order_id": 1,
                    "unit": 2,
                    "expiration_date": "2019-01-26",
                    "total_stocks": 100000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 11033,
                    "available_stocks": 88967,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-20 14:48:16"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 9,
                    "ingredient_id": 1,
                    "warehouse_id": 2,
                    "receive_order_id": 1,
                    "unit": 2,
                    "expiration_date": "2020-06-29",
                    "total_stocks": 1000000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 0,
                    "available_stocks": 1000000,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-20 14:48:16"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 18,
                    "ingredient_id": 1,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "receive_order_id": 3,
                    "unit": 2,
                    "expiration_date": "2018-01-22",
                    "total_stocks": 9000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 0,
                    "available_stocks": 9000,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "id": 22,
              "ingredient_id": 2,
              "request_stock_id": 6,
              "request_quantity": 200,
              "approved_quantity": 100,
              "delivered_quantity": 0,
              "delivery_status": "Open",
              "unit": {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Liter",
                "abbreviation": "L",
                "lowest_unit": "No",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": null
              },
              "created_at": null,
              "updated_at": "2018-01-28 14:17:31",
              "ingredient": {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Water",
                "description": "Water",
                "SKU": "1000001",
                "purchase_price": 50,
                "vat": 0,
                "asset_account": 1,
                "cogs_account": 14,
                "expense_account": 13,
                "sales_account": 11,
                "default_unit": 5,
                "purchase_unit": 9,
                "created_at": "2018-01-18 09:29:09",
                "updated_at": "2018-01-18 09:29:09",
                "warehouse_items": [
                  {
                    "id": 2,
                    "ingredient_id": 2,
                    "warehouse_id": 1,
                    "receive_order_id": 1,
                    "unit": 5,
                    "expiration_date": "2019-02-21",
                    "total_stocks": 1000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 200,
                    "available_stocks": 800,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-20 11:07:20"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 10,
                    "ingredient_id": 2,
                    "warehouse_id": 2,
                    "receive_order_id": 1,
                    "unit": 5,
                    "expiration_date": "2020-01-29",
                    "total_stocks": 2000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 0,
                    "available_stocks": 2000,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": "2018-01-20 11:07:20"
                  },
                  {
                    "id": 23,
                    "ingredient_id": 2,
                    "warehouse_id": 3,
                    "receive_order_id": 7,
                    "unit": 5,
                    "expiration_date": "2018-01-24",
                    "total_stocks": 2000,
                    "transfer_stocks": 0,
                    "available_stocks": 2000,
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: ca you clarify this a bit can i see you method for this.transferForm.get(); please remember that javascript is ass by reference so probably u are assign the same reference twice

Comment: @Obed. I want to transfer the values from this.openModalForm.get('rows2').value to transferForm.get('rows3').

Answer (score 0):

the FormControl has a method

```
Formcontrol.setValue(jsonRepresentationOfForm)
```

so you can call

```
transferForm.get('rows3').setValue(this.openModalForm.get('rows2').value);
```

you can use  formControl.pacthValue() too, the do similar things

check the [API](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) out

If u need to add multiple things then you need a form arra not a form component.

```
 FormArray.push(takesAnAbstraacFormControl)

FormArray.push(this.openModalForm.get('rows2').value);
```

because javascript is pass-by-reference you would have to call new on the form you pushed to the array, else all your formed pushed will have the same reference.

```
this.openModalForm.get('rows2') = resetopenModalForm();


resetopenModalForm(initialValues): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(initialValues.name, [Validators.required])
     ....initilize other controls.....
    });
  }
```

i am adding the new code down here

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl, FormBuilder, AbstractControl} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  transferForm: FormGroup;
  openModalFormArray: FormArray;
  formProperties;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initopenModalFormArray();
  }

  add() {
    this.openModalFormArray.push(this.initOpenModalForm(new EmptyFormProperties()));
    console.log(this.openModalFormArray);
  }
  onSaveQuantity(){


    console.log(this.openModalFormArray.value);

}
  delete(index: number) {
    this.openModalFormArray.removeAt(index);
  }

  reset(index: number) {
    this.openModalFormArray.at(index).reset();
  }

  initopenModalFormArray() {
    this.formProperties.forEach(formProperty => {
      this.openModalFormArray.push(this.initOpenModalForm(formProperty));
    });
  }

  initOpenModalForm(formProperties): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      expiration_date: new FormControl(formProperties.expiration_date, [Validators.required]),
      ingredient_id: new FormControl(formProperties.ingredient_id, [Validators.required]),
      ingredient_sku: new FormControl(formProperties.ingredient_sku),
      ingredient_name: new FormControl(formProperties.ingredient_name),
      unit: new FormControl(formProperties.unit, [Validators.required]),
      available_qty: new FormControl(formProperties.available_qty, [Validators.required]),
      transfer_qty: new FormControl(formProperties.transfer_qty, [Validators.required]),
    });
  }
}
```

inspiration from [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2)

Comment: @Obed. If i keep clicking the onSaveQuantity(), it would add several objects right?

Comment: No it wouldn't ,  do you want it to add several objects?

Comment: @Obed. Yes i want it to add several objects when i keep clicking onSaveQuantity().

Comment: then you need a form array not a form component

Comment: i have edited my code , but give me a moment to edit yours too

Comment: @Obed. Ok Ill wait for it. Thanks Obed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163893/discussion-between-obed-and-joseph).